# Does the fields of any other fundamental force beside electromagnetism display duality?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I've always found the duality of the electromagnetic force intriguing: Why does it seem to have two distinct facets in the static case, with Lorentz transformations transforming one field into another, while no similar structure seem to exist in the other forces of nature?

Or does it also happen for some other force but this is just not worked in this same framework?

Comment: Both electric and magnetic forces come from a single underlying electromagnetic quantum tensor. Why this particular quantum tensor behaves differently is not clear to me either. But that’s why it is one of the four fundamental interactions not two. No it doesn’t also happen for any of the other three fundamental forces. Please let me know if you come across something good about it

Comment: Both nuclear interactions have [a multiplet equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Mathematical_overview) of $F_{\mu\nu}$.